# cant receive mail but can send out via root@example.org

Tags: postfix

error log

```
Oct  6 06:09:59 ideashost postfix/smtpd[11673]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-io0-x229.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c06::229]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
Oct  6 06:09:59 ideashost postfix/smtpd[11673]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-io0-x229.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c06::229]: 454 4.7.1 <admin@ideaszambia.org>: Relay access denied; from=<isoftcom.ic@gmail.com> to=<admin@ideaszambia.org> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-io0-x229.google.com>
Oct  6 06:09:59 ideashost postfix/smtpd[11673]: disconnect from mail-io0-x229.google.com[2607:f8b0:4001:c06::229] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.ideaszambia.org, localhost
mydomain = mail.ideaszambia.org
myhostname = mail.ideaszambia.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ideaszambia.org/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.ideaszambia.org/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

where am i going wrong

Comment: mydomain is not Mail.ideaszambia.org it is ideaszambia.org. Mail.ideaszambia.org is the host name not the domain name.

Comment: Take a look at your post.  Now imagine someone else trying to read it.  Do you think they would find it a struggle to help you?

Comment: Appleoddity am redoing it 
@Womble there you go. please help

Answer (score 1):

You have configured you mailserver to accept incoming mail to these domains:

```
mydomain = mail.ideaszambia.org
myhostname = mail.ideaszambia.org
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain, localhost.ideaszambia.org, localhost
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain
```

The domain of the email address  `to=<admin@ideaszambia.org>` is not in that list and therefore the message gets rejected.  Most likely you want to add `ideaszambia.org` to the  `virtual_alias_domains` i.e.

```
virtual_alias_domains = $mydomain ideaszambia.org
```

Comment: This is my test virtual_alias_domains

postmaster@ideaszambia.org root
root@ideaszambia.org root
info@ideaszambia.org info

Am thinking its already added, admin@ideaszambia.org is predefined as admin and the rest are just created.

Comment: Please see my edit, you need to add domain to virtual_alias_domains in your main.cnf , just creating email address mappings is not enough